# Get Filename in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
function GetImageTitle(elem){
var title_attr=elem.children("img").attr("title"); //get image title attribute
$img_title.data("imageTitle", title_attr); //store image title
}
```

It outputs :

```
This is my Image
```

I want to edit the code to output the file path. e.g.:

```
http://localhost/images/gallery/bird.jpg
```

Thanks

Comment: `var title_attr=elem.children("img").attr("src");` `src` is the path of the `img`, the `tittle` is only a descriptive and alternative text

Comment: If the image isn't hosted the browser will not let you display the path of the image from the clients computer. If you attempt this it will display something like `fakepath/someimage.jpg`. If the image is hosted in the server directory you can use the image `src` to display the path > domain.com/someimage.jpg

Answer (score 1):

To get the file path of the image, you must fetch the src attribute of image.

```
function GetImageTitle(elem){
var title_attr=elem.children("img").attr("src"); //get image full path
$img_title.data("imageTitle", title_attr); //store image title
```

This will output

```
http://localhost/images/gallery/bird.jpg
```